# Link to site with internal target

Tags: html, target

I have a site with a iframe. In the iframe I load pages using "target". Now I wanna sent someone a link to a page with not the starting page loaded in the iframe but an other page. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with pure HTML. You will either need to use JavaScript to change the `iframe`'s location on page load, based on a hash in the URL (e.g. `/path/to/your/page#iframe-location`); or use a server-side language to default the `iframe`'s location based on the page URL.

Based on your experience level, the JavaScript solution may be the best for you.